# Running a console application from the command prompt without it launching a new console window

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-console

Is there a way to prevent a console application from launching a new console window if it is executed from the command prompt?  I don't know why I've never noticed this before (or if I just haven't been annoyed by it before) but I would like to be able to open a command prompt, navigate to where my console application (.exe) is and run it without it launching a new console window.

I've seen threads about how to hide the console window but my application isn't really meant to run in an automated fashion so if they run it from Explorer, I would like them to see it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A console application, when run from an existing command-line, will not create a new console window: Windows will re-use the existing window.

PE executables (i.e. `.exe` files) are marked with a flag which tells the OS if it's a console application or not: if it is marked as a console application then Windows will re-use the console window used to launch it, or create a new window if it was launched from a GUI process (such as Windows Explorer). In .NET applications, this flag is controlled by the Application Type drop-down in Project Properties (where it lists either "Windows Application", "Console Application", or "Class Library").

If your program is creating a new window, then it probably has the wrong flag set OR the program code is manually calling `AllocConsole` which will create a new console window regardless of how the process was created or the PE console flag.

**Update** There is one other reason: When a console application runs under a different privilege level than its (non-elevated) parent console window, then UAC will require it to be in its own window.

Comment: Maybe that's why I've never noticed this before. The odd thing in my case though is that that Output type in the application properties is set to "Console Application" and `AllocConsole` isn't being used. There are only two other things I can think of that could possibly factor in here. 1) The solution contains three projects and an Install Shield Setup. One project is a shared class library, one is a WPF application and one is the console application. They deploy in parallel. 2) The console application does have an app.manifest so that it doesn't throw goofy errors when deployed.

Comment: @Ryan I suggest making a copy of your solution, then removing everything until you get to the minimum code/files required to reproduce the problem, then post the code here to StackOverflow.

Comment: Figured it. In my app.manifest I have the `requestedExecutionLevel` set to `requireAdministrator` because the application does need administrative level access. I changed the value to `asInvoker` and it executed in place (as you mentioned above Dai). UAC is what is causing it to behave this way. I'm not signing the file because the application is really for internal use only. Anyway, that appears to be the real issue in my case!

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that's another cause. I'll amend my answer now.

Comment: @Ryan If the application does need admin access, then you can solve your problem another way: run it from an administrative command line window instead of a regular one.  (Hint: in Windows 7, press the Windows key, type "cmd" at the Start Menu and press CONTROL-ALT-ENTER.  In Windows 8 I think the shortcut is Windows-X and then A.)

Comment: Thank you! The problem is solved.
In my case, I had to run the `command prompt` **as administrator**.